# compiler dont recognize parameters in action listener class

Tags: java, swing, compiler-construction, jpanel, actionlistener

im trying to build matrix of JPanels and button of clear, when you press the screen the panel in the specific place  colored in black , and when you press clear everything  got white. i dont know why but in my action listener class it dont recognize paramrters and object  from the Painters class.

#### Cell.java

```
package Paint;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Cell extends JPanel {

    private JPanel p;

    public Cell() {
        this.p = new JPanel();
        this.setSize(50, 50);
        this.setBackground(Color.white);
    }
}
```

#### Matrix.java

```
package Paint;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Matrix extends JPanel {

    private Cell[][] matrix;

    public Matrix(int row , int col) {
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(row, col));
        this.matrix = new Cell[row][col];
        for(int i=0; i< row ; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<col; j++) {
                this.matrix[i][j] = new Cell();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Painter.java

```
package Paint;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;    
import javax.swing.*;

public class Painter extends JPanel {

    private JButton btn;
    private Matrix matrix ;
    private int row , col;

    public Painter(int row , int col) {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
        this.matrix = new Matrix(row, col);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        btn = new JButton("clear");
        this.add(matrix , BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(btn , BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource() == btn) {
                for(int i= 0; i< row; i++) {
                    for (int j= 0 ; j < col ; j++) {
                        this.matrix[i][j].setBackground(Color.white);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                for(int i= 0; i< this.row; i++) {
                    for (int j= 0 ;this.col ; j++) {
                        if(e.getSource()== this.matrix[i][j]) {
                            if(this.matrix[i][j].getBackground()== Color.white)
                                this.matrix[i][j].setBackground(Color.black);
                            else
                                this.matrix[i][j].setBackground(Color.white);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Tester.java

```
package Paint;

import javax.swing.JFrame;    
import ShayExam.MyPanel;    
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("matrix");
        frame.setSize(750, 750);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        System.out.println("before Painter");
        Painter p = new Painter( 6 , 6);
        frame.add(p);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this,
**"this"** refers to the calling instance of the class in which you are using **"this"** keyword. You can access data member of outer class directly in inner class. You can't use col in conditional part of `for` loop. `actionPerfomed()` will not get called because you have to add `ActionListener` to any instance.

This code does not have compilation error.

```
private class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == btn) {
            for(int i= 0; i< row; i++) {
                for (int j= 0 ; j < col ; j++) {
                    matrix.getCell(i,j).setBackground(Color.white);
                }
            }
        } else {
            for(int i= 0; i< row; i++) {
                for (int j= 0 ;j<col ; j++) {
                    if(e.getSource()== matrix.getCell(i,j)) {
                        if(matrix.getCell(i,j).getBackground()== Color.white)
                            matrix.getCell(i,j).setBackground(Color.black);
                        else
                            matrix.getCell(i,j).setBackground(Color.white);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and Matrix class

```
public class Matrix extends JPanel {

    private Cell[][] matrix;

    public Matrix(int row , int col) {
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(row, col));
        this.matrix = new Cell[row][col];
        for(int i=0; i< row ; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<col; j++) {
                this.matrix[i][j] = new Cell();
            }
        }
    }

    public Cell getCell(int i, int j) {
        return matrix[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: This would still cause a compile error. `Matrix` class _has_ no `getCell()` method ;-)

Comment: Sorry I created that one. I am updating the answer.

Comment: @nIcE cOw I want to accept your edit. How can I do that?

Comment: @Varun: You don't have to, my [privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), is enough for that, it is done :-) Once you will attain the reputation of `2000`, even you can also do that. Posted the link too, for you to have a look. You're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)

Comment: @Varun: I guess, till `200 reputation` points, you get `2` points to edit someone's post. So you can try that too, if you find, someone's post needs editing :-)

Comment: @nIcE cOw Yes, I have edited some. But first time someone edited my post.

Answer (score 3):

1. (In Painter$MyActionListener class) - when you use `this` in the `ActionListener` class, the `this` is referring to the `ActionListener` class, (which does not have those variables) and not the `Painter` class variable. (row, col, matrix). So get rid of all the `this` you are using in the `ActionListener` class or use `Painter.this.variable`
2. (in Painter class) -  `Matrix matrix` needs to be a `[][]` since you are trying to use `matrix[i][j]`. I see the Matrix class has a 2d array of Cells. You may want to have a `getMatrix()` method that returns the 2d array of Cells, inside the Matix class. And instead of `Marix matrix` use `Cell[][] martrix` and `Matrix m` and then do `matrix = m.getMatrix()`. Or something to that extent

Answer (score 3):

```
Painter.this.matric[i][j]
```

You can access specifying class of `this`

Comment: This would still cause a compile error. `Matrix matrix` isn't a 2D array ;-)

Comment: @peeskillet you are right. I just pointed main idea of accessing main class via **this**